# What is the age of my columbia clippe bicycle, maunfactured by westfield Mfg.?

Tags: frames

My bike is a columbia clipper manufactured by westfield mfg.  Crank bottom serial # starts out B...083   can anyone tell me its age.  I'm in the process of restoring it.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome aboard.

Normally frame / serial numbers are few and far between and often get overlooked on here because normally they don't lead anywhere.

However in this case as it's pre-war and you had the basic info needed (Westfield, Columbia, Clipper) the info was actually quite easy to track down.

Thanks to a guy called Mercian [over here at The Classic & Antique Bicycle Exchange](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/westfield-frame-numbers-1933-1945.100743/)

It appears "B" was the date letter for 1935 (you need to scroll down a lot on the page i linked)

Some great info and images of various Westfield Columbia's, good luck with the restoration

Thanks to @Andrew below for the following link.

[Columbia Manufacturing FAQ](http://www.columbiamfginc.com/content/frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: The columbia website indicates B serial numbers as 1937: http://www.columbiamfginc.com/content/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: @Andrew, I actually hadn't seen that site but i will add the link to my answer so the OP has a couple of places of reference points. The link i posted has only reference to "B" being 1935, unfortunately Colombia have a possible 2 answers 37 or 56? Best to reference both sites and let the OP have browse.